# why round doesn't truncate

Tags: sql, rdbms, rounding, truncate

Please help me understand why

```
select round((sum(t.ResolvedCalls) over()) * 100.00 / (sum(t.OpenedCalls) over ()),2,1) as overall_pct
```

results in 
    67.2700000000000

...when I was expecting 67.27.

I'm looking to round to 2 decimals and then truncate after that. I thought that round with 3 parms would accomplish this.
What am I missing here?

Comment: Well, `ROUND` isn't changing the data type, just rounding your result. What's the datatype of both `ResolvedCalls` and `OpenedCalls`?

Comment: `67.2700000000000` IS `67.27`  If you don't want all of those trailing zeros convert the result to `NUMERIC(5,2)`

Comment: 67.2700000000000 is exactly the same as 67.27 (as a number). Depending on what database you are using, you may find a function to print it out as a string, if you want a string.

Comment: ResolvedCalls and OpenedCalls are just aggregate counts. I was more concerned with the trailing zeros.  I guess my expectations were similar to result of using numeric().  Thanks for the feedback(s).  Cast as numeric(5,2) will work.

Comment: Please tag RDBMS. You should have seen [a pop up](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274634/73226) already reminding you of this when asking.